# visual studio html intellisense with angular project

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have an angular project work space in visual studio code but either from a recent update or settings, when an HTML file is open it doesn't show variables used in the component. I should be able to see variables or angular directives when I start to type them in my html.
Im working angular 7 and the latest version of VS code (June 7th 2019).

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution, that is a year old but works, from github!

https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/312#issuecomment-465990352